# Real-time price data for cryptocurrencies

Tags: exchanges

I need some source (preferably free) for real-time (or some reasonable time lag) for quotes of cryptocurrencies. Can you suggest anything?

What does Kraken or Poloniex use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the price on an exchange will be determined by the user. the user (=trader) decide for how much {money, other coins, whatever} they buy or sell a coin/token.

if you want to have the prices of many exchanges/many coins/many token you can use the [coinmarketcap api](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) for example. coinmarketcap calculates the average price of several well known exchanges. but in practice *every* exchange has an api which provides the data of the current orders/price. see for example api-docs: [gdax](https://docs.gdax.com), [poloniex](https://poloniex.com/support/api/), [binance](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md), [bitfinex](https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs), [bittrex](https://bittrex.com/home/api), [kraken](https://www.kraken.com/help/api).